# How do I give permissions to update/init private submodules in Travis CI build?

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages, git-submodules

I added a private submodule to my Travis CI build. During the build when it tries to update the submodule from the private repo, I get the following error.

`The command "eval git submodule update --init --recursive " failed.`

I am assuming the problem is that it won't allow access to the private submodule. I was looking here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#dedicated-user-account

I tried to generate SSH keys and RSA private keys, but I don't know where they should be stored?

I think I have to generate new keys and store them on travis, but I'm not sure where.

Has anyone used private submodules in Travis CI builds?

Thanks.